# How to make a semi circle chart in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, charts

I am having a data like,

```
  {
    "initial": {
      "unit": "GB",
      "value": 2
    },
    "remaining": {
      "unit": "GB",
      "value": 0.2
    },
    "type": "Internet",
  }
```

Where the `initial` value is total gb of mobile data and `remaining` consists of the remaining data available.

**Requirement:**

My requirement is like the below image,

[image]

I have tried with pure HTML and CSS like here, But **issue here is that everything is hard coded** .. So if we have some percentage then we need to adjust the css class `.sc-percentage` accordingly

```css
body { background-color:#555888; font-family:sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:center }
code { display:inline-block; max-width:600px;  padding:80px 0 0; line-height:1.5; font-family:monospace; color:#ccc }

.sc-gauge  { width:200px; height:200px; margin:200px auto; }
.sc-background { position:relative; height:100px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#fff; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; }
.sc-mask { position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; left:20px; height:80px; background-color:#555888; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0 }
.sc-percentage { position:absolute; top:100px; left:-200%; width:400%; height:400%; margin-left:100px; background-color:#00aeef; }
.sc-percentage { transform:rotate(25deg); transform-origin:top center; }
.sc-min { float:left; }
.sc-max { float:right; }
.sc-value { position:absolute; top:50%; left:0; width:100%;  font-size:48px; font-weight:700 }
```

```html
<code>

    To change the current value of the Gauge, you need to change 88 to something else in HTML section and update the .sc-percentage rotate value from 158deg to something else.
    
    This will be a part of the Simple Chart library.

</code>


<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
      <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask"></div>
      <span class="sc-value">0.2</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>
```

I would like to form a chart exactly as like given in the above image.

I am open to implement any kind of library like chartjs, d3, apex etc.., that supports this feature of having semi circle..

As I am a beginner with this scenario, kindly help me to resolve the feature as I am stuck for very long time with this.

A big thanks in advance..

Comment: It looks like in react you want to manually set the CSS on the element to set `transform:rotate(25deg)` to the degrees representing the percent the bar is done. You could either animate this in React by updating the degrees every frame, or you could use CSS animation to set the degrees to something and let the CSS animation handle the transition between the two

Comment: @AndyRay, Thanks for your comment.. Will it be enough to handle like the above given snippet alone? Because I am in the need to place the middle range also ```1``` at the top.. I am able to place ```0``` and ```2``` start and end respectively but also need to place middle range ```1``` at the top..

Comment: @AndyRay, Could you please kindly help me with solution if you could which will give me better understanding of things as I am a beginner.. If the things are in react way of handling then that would also be much more beneficial as I am using react application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React component:

```js
const data = {
  "initial": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 2
  },
  "remaining": {
    "unit": "GB",
    "value": 0.9
  },
  "type": "Internet",
};

function SemiCircleChart({min, max, value}){

  const angle = (value / max) * 180;
  const style = {'--angle': angle + 'deg'};

  return (
    <div class="sc-gauge">
      <div class="sc-background">
        <div class="sc-percentage" style={style}></div>
        <div class="sc-mask"></div>
        <span class="sc-value">{ value }</span>
      </div>
      <span class="sc-min">{ min }</span>
      <span class="sc-max">{ max }</span>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <SemiCircleChart
      min={0}
      max={data.initial.value}
      value={data.remaining.value}
    />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
:root {
  --angle: 90deg;
}

body {
  background-color: #555888;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}

code {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #ccc
}

.sc-gauge {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #555888;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0
}

.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-min {
  float: left;
}

.sc-max {
  float: right;
}

.sc-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<code>
    This will be a part of the Simple Chart library.
</code>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

**Old answer**:

You just need to use a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

Declare a variable like:

```
:root{
  --angle: 90deg;
}
```

and use it like:

```
.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(var(--angle));
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

You can update this variable as style attribute from JavaScript:

```
element.style.setProperty("--angle", '180deg');
```

`180deg` would be full arc.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but here I am also in the need to place top center label which will denote the value of ```1``` as that is the average between ```0``` and ```2``` ..

Comment: Also in your solution, the remaining gb is showing as ```50%``` (as in the middle of chart) but actually it would have only lesser than ```25%``` or something as remaining is only ```0.2gb``` ..

Comment: I am okay to implement ```javascript/react``` way also with additional libraries but I am in the need to implement exact solution as like the image in the question..

Comment: @Undefined let me see if I can quickly put together some js based on your given data structure

Comment: @Undefined just updated the answer. You can improve it further by extracting it to function/wrapping in a component library of your choice etc

Comment: @Undefined This looks to be a solid solution/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with animation: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-moon-t08hp?file=/src/App.js

You can set style variables in React, which is what this Codesandbox does:

```
        <div
          class="sc-percentage"
          style={{ transform: `rotate(${(percent / 100) * 180}deg)` }}
        ></div>
```

And it uses a setInterval to toggle the percent.

The animation between the two percents is achieved simply with a [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) property:

```css
.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Andy, Could you kindly help me to place an average value at the top center of the chart like in the image in question? Which is ```1``` right now for the given values as ```0``` is the starting point and ```2``` is the ending point..

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. What code have you tried and what are you having trouble with that isn't working? The CSS you pasted should give you a good starting point for figuring out how to add a third sc-middle element and how to position it.

Comment: Okay Andy, I understand yoyr comment and your help is highly appreciable..